# Wake-on-wan - как реализовать

Tags: windows, консоль, маршрутизация, lan, ethernet

Имеется ПК на ОС Windows, роутер Airport Express, статический IP адрес. ПК соединен с роутером по проводу.

После настройки Wake On Lan все работает прекрасно - компьютер включается с телефона, с другого пк без проблем. Но только внутри локальной сети. Если пытаться послать магический пакет используя 4g на своем телефоне, то это не увенчается успехом и ПК будет выключен.

Я понимаю, что wake-on-lan работает только внутри сети, но вопрос в другом. Можно ли отправить магический пакет через интернет, находясь в другой сети?

Comment: уточнение: на роутере перекрыты порты UDP 4343, 9 и 7

Comment: если провайдер выдает рутеру белый IP, то по типовой инструкции можно открыть порт 9 наружу для пробуждения. При динамическом IP испoльзовать DynamicDNS. Хотя на форумах Эпла пользователи пишут, что проброс внутрь широковещательных пакетов не работает. Можно попытаться сделать так, как описано в этой [ветке](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1680807) форума

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Порт во внешке открываешь любой выше, например 4009, и пробрасывай его на 9. Адрес укажи 255.255.255.255 если роутер поймет его, если не поймет, попробуй 192.168.х.255. Тут главное чтоб пакет ушел в нужный порт свича с портом udp 9.

Тут главное выплюнуть пакет в порт свича на котором стоит комп.

Если выкидывать на юникаст адрес, то сначала отработает arp, а только потом полетит пакетик. В этом вся проблема.

На некоторых сетевых можно настроить ответ арп в спящем режиме вроде..

Comment: Перенастроил переадресацию портов 
Public UDP: 4343
Private UDP: 9

Маска подсети 255.255.255.255, пакет получен от телефона на 4g
Спасибо большое!

Comment: подскажи еще пожалуйста: пакет я действительно получаю и с помощью него могу включить компьютер но 15-20 минут спустя после выключения от пакета он не просыпается больше. как быть? @eri

Comment: В биосе должно быть разрешенно просыпаться из выключенного, а не только из режима ожидания. Плюс в винде настроенно в свойствах сетевой.

Answer (score 1):

проблема в том, что магия пакета работает на 2 уровне, а маршрутизация убивает всю информацию на данном уровне. Самый простой вариант организовать скрипт на роутере или другом устройстве за роутером, чтобы они по вашему внешнему запросу отсылали магический пакет внутри сети.

Comment: А как же бродкасты)